# How many sample needed for 95% confidence of a rule

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

I've got an electronical component measuring some voltage. The documentation of this component say the maximum error of measurement of this component is 3%.

Assuming a chosen component always do the same error of measurement the question is: How many successful tests (error <= 3%) on different components I need to say, with 95% confidence, that this specification rule is true?

My intuition was to do something like a proportion test with H0: p0 = 1, and calculate the minimum n for 95% confidence level of accepting this hypothesis. But the test can't handle n(1 − p0) < 5.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your null hypothesis is $H_0: p_0 = 1$. It is the hypothesis that there is no random components in the output. So I do not think that statistics covers this situation.

For example, you observed 10,000 times of safe taking off and landing of the airplanes, but you still can not say the taking off and landing of the airplanes are absolutelt safe.

Comment: Thank for your answer! So maybe the thing I can do is to put $H_0: p_0 = threshold$ and $H_1: p_0 > threshold$. So for 0.99, we have $$H_0 : p_0 = 0.99$$ and $$H_1: p_0 > 0.99$$. So at this moment, we need exactly $$n > 5/(1 − p0) = 500$$ to reject null hypothesis (assuming all attempts will be < 3%). Am I wrong?

Comment: When calculating the sample size, $H_1$ should be specify to a fixed value.